# How to position a close icon (top right) in the popup with below DOM structure?

Tags: html, css, dom

I need to position a popup close icon with below DOM structure

```
<div class="DIV1"></div>
<div class="DIV2">Content of the POPUP</div>
```

My output should be like this:

[image]

Positioning should work for all screens. Please give me the answer with this DOM structure.

NOTE: Popup content div and close icon div are separated.

Comment: You need to wrap those `div`s with another div. And then you will need some positioning with CSS. Can you share the code from the picture you are showing?

Comment: @caramba I need position for above DOM structure. DIV2 is inside DIV1 then It's easy to position in top right. But it is not inside DIV1. so when I try it, It won't stick in a position when I change the resolution. Is it possible these 2 doms are wrapped with parent DOM? but this parent contains more children

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kumarokm1995/zod4k1k2/1/ look at this jsfiddle. I can able to control x-axis but i can't control y-axis. even x-axis has some slight changes in positioning

Comment: I don't see the X in your fiddle. anyway, it depends on what you really want/need .. you could try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kso46dhw/

Comment: Are you going to use script when closing it?

Comment: x-axis is not positioned in https://jsfiddle.net/kso46dhw/

Comment: yes i will use script for closing it @LGSon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```css
.close
{
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;        
    width: 10px;
    height : 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px 10px;
    left: 77%;
    margin: calc(20% - 35px) 0 0 8%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.popup
{
    width: 77%;
    margin: 20% 8%;
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color : white;
    height : 300px;
    overflow : scroll;
   }
```

```html
<div class="close">X</div>

<div class="popup">

<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>fgh<br>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer.

Comment: @Kumaravel You're welcome ... and now you have upvote capabilities as well :)

Comment: @Kumaravel My I ask why you removed your accept? ... the other answer does not solve it with your existing question requirements, _with the existing DOM_

Comment: both answers correct with my requirements. but I can accept answer for one person. :(

Comment: @Kumaravel Yes, only one, and you decide which, I just wanted to understand why you took mine off .... as with your requirements/question there were no outer `div`

Comment: @Kumaravel And if you favor the other, which I think has a better structure than your original, please feel free to accept it

Answer (score 1):

look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se99ptzw/)

you can replace IDs with classes

```css
#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#close{
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}
#content{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="close">x</div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus molestias saepe mollitia unde sint voluptas nostrum, cumque minima, ea quam maiores cum vitae ipsa hic! Quas nesciunt officiis alias laudantium!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Saif . Works fine.Superb